# How to auto add copyright when user copy the web content in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

```
setClipboardText = function(event) {
  var htmlData, node, textData;
  event.cancelable = true;
  event.preventDefault(); //add this code will make iOS paste null
  node = document.createElement('div');
  node.appendChild(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
  htmlData = '<div>Some copyright' + node.innerHTML + '</div>';
  textData = 'Some copyright' + window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

  event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', htmlData);
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', textData);
};

copyrightRange = document.getElementById('content-copyright');

copyrightRange.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  setClipboardText(e);
```

The code above will work on the pc browsers, but on the mobile browsers, it doesn't work. I have test the problem is `event.preventDefault();`.But without this, my function will not make sense.Can somebody help me?

Comment: Just for the record, I *absolutely hate* sites that mess with your clipboard.

Comment: I don't like it either, but it's my job now, I have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, since I'm not testing this myself, but I think you want to use `return false`, which is supposed to prevent the default event behaviour. You might also try event.stopPropagation() alongside return false.

There is more info at the Mozilla Developer Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/More_Event_Handlers#Prevent_Default_Action. What I'm confused about in this page is the precise definition of an "attribute listener" in this quote:

> Alternatively, for attribute event listeners, you can just return false from the code.

This question's top two answers are also mostly relevant:

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Can you visit `www.zhihu.com` with mobile browser, then copy some answer more than 42 characters to memorandum，you can find the copyright.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone :|